# Azure SQL - No more manage tool via portal and SSMS 2016 has no table designer

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms, azure-sql-database

*- For the down voter: This is not a rant in anyway, been using Azure since last 4 years, totally fan -*

So far I was using the Manage option of the previous Azure portal, now that the new portal is enabled by default, they does not seems to have transferred the Azure SQL manage option.

SQL Server Management Studio 2016 CTP 3.1 (November 2015) does not offer me any kind of table designer.

Now I know, I could type everything into T-SQL, but still for schema manipulation, the table designer is still the quickest.

Is there not any way to have the old "manage" Silverlight interface or having SSMS handling table design with indexes etc?

In fact, I'm reading everywhere that since SSMS 2014 there has been support to Azure SQL table designer, still I don't have that option on the latest version of SSMS. Is the 2016 have less support for Azure SQL than 2014?

I don't have Visual Studio anymore, and frankly I would rather not want to install this just to have a more comfortable time designing a Azure SQL schema.

Any pointer, how do you handle this?

Comment: why the -1? Being turning Google up-side-down to try a satisfying solution and nothing was found, why down voting, is it not a legit developer question?

Comment: The down voting is likely due to what appears to be a rant about Azure's feature set, which is outside of the control of most of this community. For the time being, you can still use Manage.WindowsAzure.com, in IE or FireFox, to access the Silverlight page. I believe you can also access your Azure db from SSMS, as long as your IP has been added to the allowed addresses.

Comment: @AWinkle thanks for the reply, my bad if it sounded like a rant, was not. The real question I guess is why my SSMS 2016 does not have the Azure feature that should be there since the 2014 version.

Comment: Hi Dominic. This functionality should be available in the SSMS November 2015 release. When you open SSMS, can you verify which version you are using? Under Help>About, you should see 13.0.800.111

Comment: One simple alternative is to install SQL Express, and do development on a local database.  Then script out the schema changes with SSMS and run them on Azure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Table Designer for Azure SQL Database V12 has been enabled from SQL Server Management Studio June 2015 Release.
Source : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlreleaseservices/archive/2015/06/24/sql-server-management-studio-june-2015-release.aspx

You're saying that you're using the last SSMS version (November 2015) but are you using a V12 server on Azure?

Regards,

Comment: Ho, appears the Database is v11 even though we've created it in mid-October, I guess this explains why the manage.windowsazure.com's manage Silverlight option works. There's a schedule update for the server where the DB is running, will test the SSMS CTP 3.1 once it's updated. Thanks for the heads-up was certain it was already on v12

Comment: Just tested that the most recent version of SSMS ( 13.0.800.111, November 2016) release works with table designer and a V12 Database.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

Comment: Yes, Azure auto-upgraded server during night, and yes the Design option on SSMS Nov 2015 is there now.